# Automatically generating cython declarations from c++ code

Tags: python, c++, cython

In order to use c++ classes in cython code you need to write [these cython cdef declarations](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/WrappingCPlusPlus). Is there a tool that generates these declarations
automatically from e.g. a C++ header file? If not, is there a reason why this is not common
practice, and thus why I probably shouldn't try to do this?

Comment: I don't believe there is. I believe the reason why not is that parsing C++ is pretty hard, and even if you could do it doesn't _all_ map to Cython perfectly. SWIG does manage to do this, and basically manages but finds it quite difficult (see http://www.swig.org/article_cpp.html). (Also, I've voted to close because recommendation for tools are off topic...)

Comment: Its not about recommending a tool its about whether such a thing exists and whether or not the entire approach is feasible.

Comment: It's basically feasible, provided you're prepared to handle the confusing corner cases manually yourself. You could certainly write something that does the bulk of the work automatically.